# Is it possible when i install graphic tablet in my computer works in my web application using signature_pad.js

Tags: javascript, digital-signature

I want to buy a graphic tablet because I have a web application (Student Directory System). I want to save signature of students from graphic tablet. Is it possible that pen pressure will work in web application?

There are javascript plugins of signature pad. When I install graphic tablet, will the pen pressure also work here ([javascript plugins](https://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/))?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the graphic tablet acts as a mouse then you will be fine. The pressure is a different thing, though. Mouse events don't have anything like "pressure", and the "plugin" you mention tries to simulate pressure by assuming that a slow speed in the way you move the mouse is equivalent to applying more pressure to the pen. It might now work for everyone.

Comment: But in js plugin, when I hover the mouse in the sensitive part of demo surface, nothings happen. however when i  hold and drug the mouse it works (maybe seems has a pressure acting hold + drugging the mouse).

Comment: Well yes, that's exactly how I suppose graphic tablet works. They send click events when you touch the surface with the stylus. I might be wrong, though.